# Showing that $(\sup S)^2 = 2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am sitting with chapter one of "The How & Why of One Variable Calculus" by Amol Sasane and in example 1.12 he let $S:= \{x \in \mathbb R : x^2 \leq 2\}$ and proceeds to show that since $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $1 \in S$ then $S$ is nonempty, and furthermore since $x^2 \leq 2 \implies x \leq 2$ we have an upper bound of $S$.

Thus $u_* := \sup \ S$ exists and ${u_{*}}^2 = 2$. He shows that ${u_{*}}^2 = 2$ by showing that it can't be either ${u_{*}}^2 < 2$ nor ${u_{*}}^2 > 2$. This he does, by considering the different cases in relation to a certain variable, r. He let $r := u_* - \frac{{u_*}^2 - 2}{u_* + 2} > 0$.

What I don't understand is the reasoning behind how he forms this r. I see that it can be useful for the numerator in the fraction to be equal to $u_*^2 - 2.$  What I don't understand is the rest of the definition of r. Is he making use somehow that $u_* \geq 1$? And if yes, why let the denominator in the fraction be $u_* + 2$?

Thank you for your time.
Regards, 
Isak

Comment: The idea is if $u^2\ne2$ then $u-\frac{u^2-2}{u+2}$ is closer to $\sqrt2$ than $u$ is

Comment: Note that $r=u - \frac {u^2-2}{u+2} =\frac{2u+2}{u+2}; $ so when $u=\sqrt 2, r=u$

Comment: Take case where $u_*^2<2$. In that case we are supposed to find a $u$ such that $0<u^2-u_*^2<2-u_*^2$. Now factorize $u^2-u_*^2$ and note that the factor $(u+u_*) <2+u_*$.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that if $u_*^2\ne 2$ then $r$ is closer to $\sqrt 2$ than $u_*$ is.

In the case where  $u_*>\sqrt2,$ $$2u_*+u_*^2>2u_*+2$$ so $$\color{red}{u_*>\frac{2u_*+2}{u_*+2}=r},$$ and since $\sqrt2>1,$ we also have  $$u_*\sqrt2(\sqrt2-1)>2(\sqrt2-1),$$ i.e., $$2u_*-\sqrt2u_*>2\sqrt2-2,$$ i.e., $$2u_*+2>\sqrt2(u_*+2),$$ i.e., $$\color{red}{r=\frac{2u_*+2}{u_*+2}>\sqrt2}.$$ Similar considerations hold in the case where $u_*<\sqrt2$.

Comment: Note:  if we were to define $r:=u-\frac{u^2-2}{u+\sqrt2}$, then we would have $r=\sqrt2,$ but we don't necessarily have $\sqrt2$ so instead we put $u+\mathbf 2$ in the denominator as the next best thing

Comment: If we put $u+\mathbf1$ in the denominator in that definition, we could not say $r>\sqrt2$